# Use of should.js with Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, should.js

I want to use should.js together with mocha in a Node.js projects which I write in Coffeescript.

In pure Javascript a expression in should.js is like

```
(function(){
  throw new Error('fail');
}).should.throw();
```

Now I want to write the same expression in Coffeescript. Something like

```
object.function().should.throw
```

But that compiles to

```
object["function"]().should["throw"];
```

Where is my mistake in my Coffescript code?

Comment: Where does `object.function` come from? Why do you call it?

Comment: This is just a placeholder. The code I use is
    `testModel = new DBModel()
    testModel.get().should.throw()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code I use is `testModel = new DBModel() testModel.get().should.throw()`

As far as I can see from the pure-JS-example, you should not invoke the function that you want to test - it's result will likely not have the `should` method. Use this instead:

```
testModel = new DBModel();
testModel.get.should.throw();
```

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right. `testModel.get.should.throw` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you write object.function() in your coffeescript. I think the coffeescript to compile to your JS should be:

```
(->
  throw new Error('fail')
).should.throw()
```

Comment: No, there is the same problem. This compiles to
`(function() {
  throw new Error('fail');
}).should["throw"]();`

Comment: @rotespferd: Isn't that exactly what you want?